# Using "which" keyword in plot command

Tags: r

I came across this code while coding for agglomerative clustering in R language.I am not getting the use of "which" keyword inside plot command:

```
xy <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
library(cluster)  # for "agnes()" and "diana()" functions
ah <- agnes(xy)  # notice that the number of clusters is not specified
plot(ah,which=2) # plot only the dendrogram
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Please read `?plot.agnes`.

Comment: here `which = 2` means that the second diagram will be plotted, try directly `plot(ah)`, the dendrogram will appear in second position.